# Detail information about executed program [PYCharm]

Tags: python-3.x, memory-management, time, pycharm

I would like to see detailed information about memory usage, execution time etc. of a program I make in PYCharm.

Is there any way to view this? Maybe there is some other program that will give me info about *.py files?